# In forms.ModelForm, Select dropdown not displaying values in queryset() correctly

Tags: python, django

i want to get a list of users and populate it in the select dropdown, but the values don't format properly.

```
[models.py]
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField()
  author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)

[forms.py]
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','author']

    widgets = {
      'author': Select(attrs={'style': 'width: 400px;'}),
    }

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['author'].queryset = User.objects.values_list('first_name')
```

and this is what Select dropdown for Author shows:

[image: Author]

how do i make it shown like below:

```
-----
Admin
John
```

Comment: Why are you setting the author queryset to a values_list of last names? This is your problem

Comment: By default, if i don't specify the queryset, the Select dropdown would display the username by default, that's not what i want. I want to override the username and display the names instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override the label used in a `ModelChoiceField` you need to create a subclass and override `label_from_instance`. [At the end of the docs for the field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField

class UserChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.first_name

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

   author = UserChoiceField(User.objects.all())

   class Meta:
       model = Post
       fields = ['title','author']

       widgets = {
          'author': Select(attrs={'style': 'width: 400px;'}),
       }
```